# Android Custom list inflateException error

Tags: java, android, custom-lists

I am getting an error when populating my customList at the point of init'ing my inflator.
LogCat error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error
>   inflating class

I populate a `hashmap<string, string>` successfully. Then i add this to a `arrayList<HashMap<string, string>.`.. all of this in a background thread.

I then get my list ' `list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);`' and setAdapter for it.

Updated my question - if i remove the imageviews from the contact_list_row.xml it works! this is wrecking my head!

The error comes when i run the following line

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_row, null);
```

The funny thing is once i get the 'application has stopped' error and back out of the activity and press it again the custom list view is populated.

```
    class refreshThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            rDialog = new ProgressDialog(Cool_Activity.this);
            rDialog.setMessage("Analysing your buddys. Please wait...");
            rDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            rDialog.setCancelable(false);
            rDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
        {           
            //What to output in each listitem in UI
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("id", "1");
                map.put("contact", contact);
                map.put("Sent", "Sent: "+"0.1");
                map.put("Received", "Received: "+String.format("%.1f", score));
                map.put("duration", type);
                map.put("thumb_url", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg");
                map.put("sent_value", "0.01");
                map.put("rec_value", score.toString());

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                resultsList.add(map);

            //}
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
        {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all questions
            rDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    /**
                     * Updating stats ui
                     * */            
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
                    adapter=new Contacts_LazyAdapter(Cool_Activity.this, resultsList);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    // Click event for single list row
                   /* list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                        }
                    });*/

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

My Adapter logic ....

```
public class Contacts_LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList <HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public Contacts_LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_row, null);

    TextView contact= (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_name); // contact
    TextView sent = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.TextView_SentResult); // sent result
    TextView received = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.TextView_ReceivedResult); // received result
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // possible future change ...
    ImageView sent_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_app); //get sent personalitymage
    ImageView rec_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.rec_image); // get received personality image
    HelpfulMethods helpful = new HelpfulMethods();

    HashMap<String, String> contact_info = new HashMap<String, String>();
    contact_info = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    contact.setText(contact_info.get(Contacts_CompositeListViewActivity.KEY_CONTACT));
    sent.setText(contact_info.get(Contacts_CompositeListViewActivity.KEY_SENT));
    received.setText(contact_info.get(Contacts_CompositeListViewActivity.KEY_RECEIVED));
    duration.setText(contact_info.get(Contacts_CompositeListViewActivity.KEY_DURATION));
    helpful.getDrawableFile((float) Double.parseDouble(contact_info.get(Contacts_CompositeListViewActivity.KEY_SENT_VALUE)), sent_image);
    helpful.getDrawableFile((float) Double.parseDouble(contact_info.get(Contacts_CompositeListViewActivity.KEY_REC_VALUE)), rec_image);
    return vi;
    }
}
```

Contact_List_Row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_app"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <!-- Title Of Song -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Niamh"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_SentResult"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Sent: 17.5"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="18dip" />

    <!-- Rightend Duration -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <!-- Rightend Arrow -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_blue"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/duration"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/duration"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rec_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_ReceivedResult"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/TextView_SentResult"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/TextView_SentResult"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView_name"
        android:text="Received: 16.5"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="18dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post this code from R.layout.contact_list_row

Comment: Added it, apologies for delay...

Comment: not related to the issue bt a simple note, onPostExecute is already on the UI thread you dn't need runOnUIxx method

Comment: Updated my question - if i remove the imageIvews from the list_row.xml it works!

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning certain ids multiple times. For example:

```
...
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/duration"
...
android:id="@+id/duration"
...
```

The `+` sign only needs to be used the first time an id is used. After that, just use it as:

```
"@id/duration"
```

Comment: No still have exact same error - removed all '+' from the layout_xxxxx positioning attributes. Edited the xml in the question.

Comment: Updated my question - if i remove the imageIvews from the list_row.xml it works!